# sliding responsive nav - flash on load and responsive page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive, nav

I have made my own responsive nav using css and jquery for the nav. I want the nav to fade in on burger button click and slide into view. I have this working well. However, when the page loads or the page is made smaller, the nav is shown briefly before sliding away.

see link

www.update.jonfullerwebdesign.co.uk

```
nav {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background: rgba($dark-grey, .8);
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-height: 50px;
z-index: 999;

@include desktop {
    background: rgba($dark-grey, .7);

}

.logo {
    width: 52px;
    position: absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:10px;
    z-index: 20;
    @include desktop {
        top: 8px;
    }

}
.menu-button {
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    right:15px;
    z-index: 200;

    @include desktop {
        display:none;
    }

}

ul {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    // position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    top: 0;
    background: inherit;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 800ms ease-in;


    @include desktop {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        height: auto;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transition: none;
        background: none;

    }



    li {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;

        @include desktop {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-left: 3%;
            margin-right: 3%;
        }

        a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 44px;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding: 30px 0;


            &:hover,
            &:focus {
                color:$brand-blue;
            }
            @include desktop {
                font-size: 22px;
                padding: 5px;
            }
        }
        .active {
            color: $brand-blue;
        }
    }
}

.shown {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;

    @include desktop {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

}




$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-button").click(function(){
   $("nav ul").toggleClass("shown")
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the new transition values within your media query. Your current default is `transform: translateX(0);`

```
@media (min-width: 62rem){
    nav ul {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, however having that, then means that on my desktop nav version, the ul is still off of the page, is there any solution to this ?

Comment: It looks like you are also using `left: -100%` and `transform: translateX(-100%)`. You may want to simplify your styling by removing 1.

Comment: I have worked out what is happening but not how to fix it, so if i remove the transition completly, no flash of nav, with transition there is a flash .

It is transitioning when the desktop nav shrinks and turns into the mobile nav

Comment: If you are okay with only having the fade-in effect, you can move the `transition` property from `nav ul` to `.shown'. Unfortunately, this prevents the animation from smoothly animating out. I'll keep looking up ways to have media queries work with toggleClass.

Comment: Thanks, Aye putting the transition on the .shown works for animating one way, but then cannot have the other. Just wish i could figure out a way for it to work with both ways and no flash. It doesnt make much sense.


I know if i use display none, I cannot use animate then so that isnt an option

Comment: I know. But I know it is there haha. And as @Sanjay said you get the flash

I know what the issue is and figured out reason I haven’t seen it before in A responsive site navigation because the side nav is just that and doesn’t go into a top desktop one

My fix for this is going to be too code two navs. one for desktop and one for mobile or responsive because the issue is that when making the website responsive or when reloading the page the UL is animating from desktop media query to the mobile media query and therefore the only way around this is to code a a nav for both I believe